# Putting an image over another image on hover with jquery for a gallery

Tags: jquery, image, hover, overlay, gallery

I have a gallery and I want to overlay each image on hover with a transparent image that has a zoom icon. How can I accomplish this in the most efficient way with jQuery? All gallery images are in an `<a></a>` tag like below:

```
<a href="pictures/gallery/fullHD/1.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img src="pictures/gallery/fullHD/1.jpg" class="gallery_pic"/>
</a>
```

I looked for answers but I couldn't find any that resolve my problem. If you know a way to accomplish this without jQuery that would be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no jQuery needed here - you can use CSS alone to achieve what you require. You can use the `:before` pseudo class to add content to the `a` element which is shown on `:hover`. Try this:

```css
a:before {
    position: absolute;
    font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    content: "\f002";
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
a:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5kq28eh4/)

Note that I used [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) to add a magnifying glass icon, but you could just as easily use any image you need and set the `background-image` property instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I'm a beginner so I don't really understand what I'm supposed to do if I want to use my own image instead of FontAwesome. I would greatly appreciate it if you could clear that up. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's an updated example using a background image instead: https://jsfiddle.net/5kq28eh4/1/